# c# Select Query to fetch datatable records

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datatable

I have datatable like below.

```
 Name    ID
 X       101
 Y       101101
 Z       101101101
 A       101101101101
 B       101102
 C       103101
 D       103102
```

I want to select all the names where id starts with 101.

How can i do that in c# datatable. Can anyone please suggest me...

Comment: cast ID to string and use `StartsWith("101")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the names where id starts with 101,

you can use Datarow to filter the data

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));

        dt.Rows.Add("ARUN", "101");
        dt.Rows.Add("Prakash","1011");
        dt.Rows.Add("Sanjay", "00101");
        dt.Rows.Add("Rahul", "00000");

        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ID like '101*'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `LINQ`  and assuming *ID* column is `string` type:

```
DataTable resultsTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(r => r.Field<string>("ID").StartsWith("101"))
                     .CopyToDataTable();
```

If *ID* column is `int` type:

```
DataTable resultsTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID").ToString().StartsWith("101"))
                     .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you just need list of names (Not data table):

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID").ToString().StartsWith("101"))
                .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Name"));
```